# Pandas dataframe to CSV python

Tags: python, pandas

I have 5kk Pandas series and try to import it to CSV.

However, when I open a CSV after import - only ~ 65k of values are there.

When I try to import the CSV file, in Python it shows all 5kk values.

Can anyone explain it? Please find export/import below:

```
 df.to_csv('unis_elastic.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index=False)

 dff=pd.read_csv('unis_elastic.csv')
```

Comment: When you `try to open CSV` in what program? Some programs, e.g. Excel (?) have 65K row limit.

Comment: The `5kk Pandas series` must be a typo, please update.

Comment: What is `5kk` values?

Comment: Thanks for help! It is 'CSV Document' on mac.

Comment: Yes, it is limit - 65535 rows on mac.

Comment: 5 kk stands for 5 million.

Comment: So it has limit to show only 65K values, but it stores all the 5KK values? Am I right?

Comment: It seems like it only shows 65k values, nevertheless, all 5kk values are stored in the file.

Answer (score 1):

Happens that, the file is actually written properly! However Numbers (mac equivalent of Excel) does not display more than 65535 rows... If the file would be  inputted within Google Spreadsheets we would probably see all 5KK values.